# Vue is rendering template tag instead of content

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to learn vue, but I can't get anything working, this is the 5th tutorial I've tried now and I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

When rendering the following code, it shows the template tagging not the intended content:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <title>Learning Vue.js</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="text" v-model="name" />
      <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        name: 'John'
      };
    }
      });
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this isn't working, I've had this issue for the last month now and can't find a solution. I'm using Firefox on a Linux computer, I've also tried it in Opera and Brave browser with the same issue, so I suspect it is my code.

Comment: Here in the above code snippet you have not closed the `script` tag and after closing the tag its working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks you, I didn't spot that till just now. Can you please post this as a solution so I can give you credit for it.

Comment: @iFunction (side note, hopefully useful) not using Chrome as your primary development tool is a mistake. Most browsers have given up the fight in browsers war and they simply use Chrome parts under the hood. FF uses Chrome dev tools for free, but they're bound to wait 6 months after a feature has been released in Chrome dev tools to include it in FF. So you're only choosing to use the same sub-components with a delay and slightly different styling. Also, developing in Chrome gives you confidence the majority of your users see what you saw while developing it.

Comment: That is an incredibly useful bit of information and likely why I am running into difficulties. I don't like Chrome at all, for me it is a horrible user experience, but for development that's a different matter. I will do my dev work using chrome in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above code snippet you have not closed the script tag.
Code after closing the tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <title>Learning Vue.js</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="text" v-model="name" />
      <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
          return {
            name: 'John'
          };
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```